What are the initialization straregies (except random) for the Q-learning algorithm on graphs?
Is there any research / ideas how to initialize Q-function (or DQN) for Q - learning on graphs ?  (Except standard random initialization - which seems very far from reasonable one)
Thanks in advance .
